# how to connect two anonymous callers together using twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am currently doing using node js twilio module for a functionality in a project that i am working on for a client. Basically the server is going to initiate a call using twilio api to call a certain person A the connect him to another person B. I am new to twilio so i am still a noob, but this is the code i have written so far. Please i need u guys input on how to achieve this. cheers

```
var client = require('twilio')(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

exports.makeCall = function(callDetails, cb) {

  client.makeCall({
    to:'+16515556677', // Any number Twilio can call
    from: TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
    url: 'https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice' // A URL that produces an XML document (TwiML) which contains instructions for the call
  }, function(err, responseData) {

      //executed when the call has been initiated.
      console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"

      var resp = new client.TwimlResponse();

      resp.say('Welcome to Acme Customer Service!')
        .gather({
          action:'http://www.example.com/callFinished.php',
          finishOnKey:'*'
      }, function() {
          this.say('Press 1 for customer service')
              .say('Press 2 for British customer service', { language:'en-gb' });
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're part way there with this, but you don't want to be creating a TwiML response in the callback to your call to `client.makeCall`. The `responseData` there is a representation of the call in Twilio's system.

What you need to do is provide a URL to the `makeCall` function that hosts some TwiML that connects the call to another phone number. Currently you have the demo URL in place, so you'll need to point that to a URL that you own.

There's a very good in depth tutorial on how to accomplish all of this on the Twilio site which you might find helps out. [You can find the tutorial here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/click-to-call-walkthrough#node/express/1), give it a go and let me know if that helps.